# Jquery Sticky side bar won't stick to bottom of website

Tags: jquery, scroll, sidebar, sticky

My sticky sidebar works when I scroll past the initial "elementpos", it goes into a fixed position and follows the screen, What I want it to do after is stick right next to the bottom of the div right next to it once I scroll to a certain point. I tried to use the footer height + a fixed amount of pixels in order to make it go into a absolute position once scrolled to that point. For some reason it's not working once I scroll past the point i'd like it to go to.

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/j05t35ax/2/

Here is my jquery script.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elementpos = $('.textbody-aa').offset().top;
    var boxesoffsetbottom = $('.boxes-buttons').offset().top + (494);
    var footerheight = $('.footer').offset().top + (-25);

    if (scrollpos >= elementpos) {
        $(".boxes-buttons").addClass("fixed")
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("static")
    }

    else if (boxesoffsetbottom >= footerheight) {
        $(".boxes-buttons").addClass("staticbottom")
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("fixed")
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("static")
    }

    else {
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("staticbottom")
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("fixed")
        $(".boxes-buttons").addClass("static")
    }

});

    .fixed {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.static {
  position: static;
}

.staticbottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 145px;

}
```

Comment: this would be great as a jsfiddle, if you can format one then it'd be easier to debug?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j05t35ax/1/ Here is exactly what I mean, the .staticbottom is where I want it to go when the red div exceedes the red div. I want the bottoms to be even

Comment: sorry the fiddle's a good start but is missing the footer and possibly the other red div?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j05t35ax/2/ Ah oops, didn't save it. There we go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, your if conditions just needed to consider the tops and bottoms, so I have added the window height to the scroll position and added the blue div's height to calculate its bottom position, to allow the red div to be restored to its fixed state. And also made sure that all three classes are addressed in each condition.

And here's a different fiddle without the class swapping: https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/p7o265nr/ which gives different advantages/disadvantages.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var elementpos = $('.textbody-aa').offset().top;
    var elementHeight = $('.textbody-aa').height();
    var boxesoffsetbottom = $('.boxes-buttons').offset().top + (340);
    var footerheight = $('.footer').offset().top - (50);

    if (scrollpos >= elementpos && (scrollpos+winHeight) < (elementHeight+50)) {
        $(".boxes-buttons").addClass("fixed");
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("static");
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("staticbottom");
    } else if (boxesoffsetbottom >= footerheight ) {
        $(".boxes-buttons").addClass("staticbottom");
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("fixed");
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("static");
    } else {
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("staticbottom");
        $(".boxes-buttons").removeClass("fixed");
        $(".boxes-buttons").addClass("static");
    }

});
```

```css
.footer{
  display:block;
  bottom:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.textbody-aa{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 1000px;
  width:150px;
  background-color: #123d80;
}

.boxes-buttons{
  height: 340px;
  width:150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right:50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.fixed{
  position: fixed;
}

.static{
  position: absolute;
  right:50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.staticbottom{
  position: absolute;
  right:50px;
  top: 710px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="textbody-aa">
Please stop at the bottom and the top
</div>
<div class ="boxes-buttons">
no
</div>

<footer class="footer">come here</footer>
```

Comment: For some reason, when I attempt to use the class swapping one on my project, I still have the same issue, it works in the fiddle but on my website when it's meant to swap to ".staticbottom" it instead swaps to ".static". I'm also using this for multiple pages, with a varying ".textbody-aa" height size, would it be better to go with the Jquery version in this case?

Comment: Sounds like in this instance the non-swapping version would be worth testing. It has the benefit of adapting for different div sizes. Class swapping has the benefit of being easier to bring new and different attributes to the table, such as changing colours and adding borders and so on - which are all just as possible in the non-swap version just a little less easy to add.